# How do I combine scatterplots to form a scatterplot matrix with common X axis for varied Y axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, scatter-matrix

my plot looks like this

[image]

This is what I've tried. I make individual scatter plots and combined them together with `grid.arrange`.

```
data(methylmercurydata) 
p1 <- ggplot(data=methylmercurydata,aes(x=MeHg, y=logTHg)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(data=methylmercurydata,aes(x=MeHg, y=OM)) + geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(data=methylmercurydata,aes(x=MeHg, y=FeRB)) + geom_point()
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3)
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want it to look like? It's easier to help you if you include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What package is `methylmercurydata` from? you probably want to re-shape your data and then do faceting if you are using `ggplot2`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this would likely be using `dplyr::facet_wrap()` after creating a longer table.

Something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

methylmercurydata %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c(logTHg, OM, FeRB), names_to = 'metric') %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(MeHG, value)) +
    facet_wrap(~metric)
```

Edit: [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) makes a good point; if you need separate scales across y, you can use `scales = 'free_y'` within the `facet_wrap` call. Likewise, `scales = 'free_x'` would provide different x axes, and `scales = 'free'` would provide different scales for each axis. One other thing to consider when recreating the above plot would be specifying the `ncol` argument as well, in this case `ncol = 1`.

Comment: Since the y-axes are a bit different, it might be good to use `facet_wrap(~ metric, scales = "free_y")`.

Comment: @r2evans Great point. I've edited my response to include the `scales` argument, as well as the `ncol` argument.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you mean by 'scatterplot matrix', but if you want to make a correlation matrix, you can use ggforce (e.g. per https://ihaddadenfodil.com/post/it-s-a-bird-it-s-a-plane-it-s-a-ggforce-function/):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)
library(palmerpenguins)

ggplot(penguins, aes(col = sex)) +
  geom_autopoint(na.rm = TRUE) +
  facet_matrix(rows = vars(bill_length_mm:body_mass_g),
               switch = "x")
```

[image: example plot]